# Does an init script always return a proper exit code when running status?

Tags: init-script, exit-status

I'm trying to write a cron job script that will check if my services are running and restart them if they aren't so I don't have to do it manually.

Now, I've looked up online how to check the status of a service in a bash script, and have found basically the following, with a few variations:

```
ps auxw | grep <service_name> | grep -v grep

if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
        /etc/init.d/<service_name> start
fi
```

I did some thinking and thought it might be a bit less hacky and more of a way of using the init script's general functionality to check it this way:

```
/etc/init.d/<service_name> status

if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    /etc/init.d/<service_name> start
fi
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't this always work? Is this a property of init scripts in general, that they return that exit code? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Under what distribution? This is not the case in Debian, but it might be the case in your distribution.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server. It seemed to work for the services that I tested it on, but I wasn't sure if it would work for all of them. This is more of a curious question, because I can obviously try this myself, and see if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not 100% of the time.  However, it's a very good yardstick.

CFEngine 3 uses this in "services promises" to check if services are running.  If the exit code of `/etc/init.d/<servicename> status` is zero, it assumes the service is running.

I have just run into BitBucket's noncompliance with this convention: `/etc/init.d/atlbitbucket status` returns 0 even when it's not running.  However, I would consider this to be undesirable behavior (a bug) in the init script, that it doesn't follow the convention.

---

Found a reference for it; the [Linux Standard Base Specification](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/iniscrptact.html) states:

> If the status action is requested, the init script will return the following exit status codes.
>
> ```
> 0         program is running or service is OK
> 1         program is dead and /var/run pid file exists
> 2         program is dead and /var/lock lock file exists
> 3         program is not running
> 4         program or service status is unknown
> 5-99      reserved for future LSB use
> 100-149   reserved for distribution use
> 150-199   reserved for application use
> 200-254   reserved
> ```

So yes, *compliant* applications can be counted upon to behave in this fashion.

Comment: And, [I've opened an issue for BitBucket to get this fixed.](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-9734)